# Convertir Objecto String a Objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Este es el string que obtengo desde una api, es un string pero no en formato json, sino en formato objeto javascript, JSON.parse no funciona porque la key no tiene doble comillas "".

```
"{text: 1}" //string
```

Ahora yo quiero convertirlo a objeto javascript que el resultado sea

```
{text:1} //object
```

Comment: la api que te entrega este valor es de tu propiedad? deberias mejorarla convirtiendola en json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías realizar esto:

```
var var1 = "{text: 1}";
var aux = var1.split(':');
aux[0] = aux[0].replace('{', '');
aux[1] = aux[1].replace('}', '');
aux[1] = aux[1].replace(' ', '');
var parsed = {[aux[0]] : aux[1]};
console.log(parsed);
```

La salida es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a dar una solución provisional y poco recomendada pero para el caso sirve

```
 var str="{text: 1}";

 eval("var j="+str);

 console.log(j);
```

Eval ejecuta strings como javascript, aunque el  uso de eval no es muy recomendado por lo que habría que buscar otra solución, si se me ocurre una forma rapida (sin tener que procesar a mano todo el string) te la pongo.